# Crouton no longer works on Chrome OS. Is there another way to install Ubuntu on it?

Tags: chrome-book, unity

thanks for taking the time to look this over.

It used to be that one could use Crouton to help install Ubuntu on Chrome OS. I did this years ago. It seems the newer versions of Chrome don't allow Crouton anymore. Just wondering if there's a way to install, say, the Unity desktop running either alongside or instead of the OS that makes with the chromebooks.

Note:
I tried the Linux stuff that now comes with the newer versions of Google's OS. But I don't know if that's the answer or, if so, how to utilize it to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Unity desktop has been discontinued. But do you want to install Ubuntu (an operating system) or [Lomiri](https://ubports.com/de/blog/ubports-blogs-nachrichten-1/post/lomiri-new-name-same-great-unity8-115) (the new name for Unity, a desktop)?

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know about the rename. I was really trying for a GUI, yeah, a desktop environment. I'm beginning to believe it's not possible anymore. Oh well.

Comment: I have no idea if it is possible or not. I am just trying to understand what you need. Ubuntu is an operating system based on Linux. Lomiri (Unity) is a desktop environment that can be installed on many different operating systems. Please ***[edit]*** your question and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.